# JS: not able to understand behaviour of hover css selector

Tags: html, css

When I hover the element with *class top_bottom_b1*, the element with *class top_bottom_b2* have to hide. I need to achieve this using css selector. I'm not sure why below code doesn't work.

```css
.top_bottom_b1{
  display: block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
.top_bottom_b2{
  display: block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:yellow;
  top: 8px;
}
.top_bottom_b1:hover .top_bottom_b2{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="top_bottom_b1"></div>
  <div class="top_bottom_b2"></div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

Even if there are multiple  elements(as shown below) between  **and** , the css selector (hover) should work.

```
<div class="top_bottom_b1"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  ... <!-- N number of divs -->
<div class="top_bottom_b2"></div>
```

Comment: `.top_bottom_b1:hover .top_bottom_b2` affects `.top_bottom_b2` elements which are *descendants* of `.top_bottom_b1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` or if their not director siblings use the [general sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) - `~`:

```css
.top_bottom_b1 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.top_bottom_b2 {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 8px;
}
div > .top_bottom_b2 {
  background: blue;
}
.top_bottom_b1:hover ~ .top_bottom_b2 {
  display: none;
}
.top_bottom_b1:hover ~ div > .top_bottom_b2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_bottom_b1"></div>

<div>I'm in the middle</div>

<div class="top_bottom_b2"></div>

<div>
  <div class="top_bottom_b2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need this code to work even if several <div> tags are between <div class="top_bottom_b1"> and <div class="top_bottom_b2"></div>. sorry for not being clear in my question, i will edit my question

Comment: Also, i need to acheive it this scenario too <div><div class="top_bottom_b2"></div></div>

Comment: i was expecting the answers to be more generic. these answers are not generic

Comment: i understand for display property hover wouldn't work properly

Comment: The cases for hover in CSS are quite specific. If you want something that will across nesting hierarchies it can be done sometimes with CSS, but maybe you need a JS solution.